# CSS: correct way to make thick <a:hover> underline for fonts with big descenders

Tags: html, css, fonts, underline

I'm a CSS-beginner. Basically I have the following html:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="news.html">О нас</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Галерея</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to have a thick underline when hovering my `a` tags, but I use a custom font with big descenders, so if I use the common trick for this:

```
a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 2px solid;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

The underline is far below the base line:[image] But I want it to look like this: [image]

I tried to do it like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="over"><a href="news.html">О нас</a></li>
    <li class="over"><a href="#">Галерея</a></li>
</ul>

.over{
    font-size: 30px;
    height:30px; // makes the text overlap this element
    overflow:visible;
}
.over:hover  {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ec6713;
}
```

But the width of the underline is the same for all the strings now: [image]

Then I added `display: inline-block;` for `.over`. But I got this: [image]

Then I changed `inline-block` to `table`, but the underline is again far below: [image]

I ended up adding an extra `span`, so now I have:

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="over"><a href="news.html">О нас</a></span></li>
    <li><span class="over"><a href="#">Галерея</a></span></li>
</ul>

.over{
    font-size: 30px;
    height:30px; // makes the text overlap this element
    overflow:visible;
    display:inline-block;
}
.over:hover  {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ec6713;
}
```

And this gives me finally the desired behaviour (the underline width is adjusted to the string width, and it's positioned close to the baseline). But is it a good practice to add an extra `span` for this purpose? Doesn't it look hacky?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `span` is a meaningless tag, so it won't give extra 'weight' to your code. Therefor, imho, it is okay to use it (but better to avoid).

Alternatively you could do the following:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="news.html">О нас</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Галерея</a></li>
</ul>
```

```css
a {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}
a:hover:after {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ec6713;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 3px;
}
```

And a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bw5v7/).

Please note that the `:after` is overlapping the `a`. I've tried adding a `z-index`, but that didn't fix it.

**OPTION 2**

Add a background-image to your `a`.

Comment: So are this three ways equally used, or CSS-experts prefer one of them for some reason?

Comment: Well, one prefers option 1, the other prefers option 2. Thereby needs to be said that my option 1 isn't [supported in all browsers](http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/). Then your own option, of my option 2 is a better solution.

Comment: As of March 20, 2019, `:before` and `:after` are all supported on most/major browsers. Go for Option 1, if you're working on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.